# MS access Limiting age to 18 or more

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm starting to learn MS-Access database for school, I'm really new at it and I didn't get much instruction from my teacher. I would really appreciate some help about setting an age limit for my costumer table. (Costumer age should not be less than 18)

I tried playing around with the validation rules , I used

<=DateAdd("yyyy", -18 , Date())

I expected this function to calculate the age of birth and limit it to 18 or more. but instead I got ( The expression you entered contains invalid syntax)

Comment: The expression works for me. You say 'costumer', do you mean 'customer'?

Comment: Yup, sorry .please excuse the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

so the mistake I made was using (,) instead of (;) 
the fixed solution is <=DateAdd("yyyy"; -18 ; Date())
and it works now.

Comment: So you are not in U.S.?

Comment: No, does it make a difference? Because I'm using an English copy of office 365.

Comment: Comma works for me, not semi-colon. It's my understanding Access setup in other countries use semi-colon in situations where U.S. would use comma. Unless Office 365 is so different from Access 2010.

Comment: I guess you’re right, when I googled it in an another language, I saw they used semi-colon.